# use laravel elequent inside loop

Tags: php, laravel, performance, eloquent

I have a query inside loop same as following:

```
$users = User::all();

foreach($users as $user) {
     $posts = Posts::where('status', 1)->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
     // do some thing ..
}
```

I converted the above code snippet into the following code:

```
$users = User::all();
$posts_tmp = Posts::where('status', 1);

foreach($users as $user) {
     $posts = $posts_tmp->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
     // do some thing ..
}
```

in second way i create new object of model outside loop and use where inside loop

Is this code snippet faster?

Has the performance increased?

in the second way run query once?

> Notice: that my question is about these two code snippet So other solutions like use `relationships` or `with()` function are not good for me

Answer (score 1):

These two queries both **n+1 queries**.

Your query will all convert into:

```sql
select * from users;
select * from posts where status = 1 and user_id = 1;
select * from posts where status = 1 and user_id = 2;
select * from posts where status = 1 and user_id = 3;
...
```

Like the eager-loading, you can use `whereIn` instead of loop:

```php
$users = User::all();
$posts = Posts::where('status', 1)->whereIn('user_id', $users->pluck('id')->toArray());
```

So the query will convert to two sql queries like this:

```sql
select * from users;
select * from posts where status = 1 and user_id in (1,2,3,...);
```